# List value from array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops

I am working in Php Laravel
Here is my output array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Blood Donate
                    [completion] => 10
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Food Donate
                    [completion] => 15
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Clothes Donate
                    [completion] => 0
                    [status] => 1
                )
         [id] => 3901ee9e-01bb-483a-9f74-8f7b76290cd5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Blood Donate
                    [completion] => 10
                    [status] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Food Donate
                    [completion] => 15
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Clothes Donate
                    [completion] => 0
                    [status] => 1
                )
            
            [id] => f2772366-4e7f-4257-90bd-8ea506dd8f84
        )  
)
```

I need to list id's where type = "Blood donation" and status = 1.
Any php function to check fields inside array?
Don't know how to proceed. First field in array was json sting. which decoded to array.

Comment: you could filter this with a custom filter using [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) which would permit you to inspect the nested data. within your filter callback you could loop over the sub items looking for the type field, and then returning true or false accordingly

Answer (score 0):

IMHO yoU need to array containing id's of all elements which has a child element type **blod donate** and status **1** Am I right.

1. Approach 1: use array_filter() to collected condition item. Then array_map() to modify representations.
2. Approach 2: Convert array into Laravel collection. Then use collection methods to run you condition query.